# Can't start httpd service due to tampered or incorrect password

Tags: linux, ssl, terminal, redhat, keytool

I am on linux Redhat OS. I was trying to import certificate using this command

```
keytool -importcert -alias 3dspace ...
```

as can be seen in the image below. But it doesn't allow to as it states that either the keystore was tampered or the password was incorrect.

To make matter worse, now I cant run the service httpd as well even though it was running prior to this problem. What can be the cause and how to solve them?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)